# How to add strings of two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array like these.

```
array("a","b","c");

array("1","2","3");
```

I have to add those items like that way.

```
$c=array("a"=>"1","b"=>"2","c"=>"3");
```

how can i retrieve each inner array by this way.

echo $c[0];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`array_combine()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

> Creates an array by using the values from the keys array as keys and the values from the values array as the corresponding values.

```
<?php
$a = array("a","b","c");
$b = array("1","2","3");
$c = array_combine($a, $b);

print_r($c);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [b] => 2
    [c] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_array = $array;
array_unshift($new_array, $value1);
array_push($new_array, $value2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_merge method for combining two arrays . Array_merge($arr1'$arr2);